# Can't find libgnutls28 for ubuntu 15.04

Tags: package-management, 15.04

Where to find libgnutls28 for Ubuntu 15.04?

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 today, and i tried to install [Kodi](http://kodi.wiki/view/Installing_XBMC_for_Linux#Installing_Kodi_on_Ubuntu-based_distributions), but it requires libgnutls28, and i was not able to find it anywhere, i tried searching for it in the [ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gnutls28&searchon=names), but it is only available for 12.04 and 14.04.

Anyone knows how can i install this package on Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: well 15.04 is not stable and fully released yet there are lots of packages that can happen to be missing yet. The package you've listed can be installed up to 14.10 for now.

Comment: Thanks, i was using kodi in 14.10, but i wanted glibc 2.21, and 15.04 had glibc 2.21, so i upgraded to 15.04, but now i need libgnutls28 and 14.10 has it and 15.04 doesn't... haha i guess i can't get everything i wan't :) .. but i guess until april it will be available, since 15.04 has libgnutls28-dbg and libgnutls28-dev in the ubuntu package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

João Carlos,

I'm testing Kubuntu 15.04 beta 2 and I had the same problem when trying to install Kodi.

Downloading Kodi deb package and editing the control file manually worked. I Think this is not recommended as it coud break the system, but it might work if you can't wait until the package is updated.

1) Add Kodi repositories as usual.
2) Install kodi's dependencies using apt, (all the required packages, but don't install "kodi" package yet).
2) Install libgnutls-deb0-28 using apt.
3) Download Kodi's deb package from ppa

https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/kodi_14.2%7Egit20150327.1058-final-0vivid_all.deb

4) Uncompress the deb package
mkdir common
dpkg -x kodi_14.2~git20150327.1058-final-0vivid_all.deb common
dpkg --control kodi_14.2~git20150327.1058-final-0vivid_all.deb

5) Edit DEBIAN/control and "fix" the broken dependencies.

Edit the "DEBIAN/control" file with vi or any text editor, and search for "libgnutls26 | libgnutls28" (in the "Depends:" section of the file).
Replace them with "libgnutls-deb0-28".

vi DEBIAN/control
cp -a DEBIAN/ common/

6) Build the fixed package.

dpkg -b common kodi_14.2~git20150327.1058-final-0vivid_all.deb

7) Install it using dpkg.

dpkg -i kodi_14.2~git20150327.1058-final-0vivid_all.deb

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you man, i appreciate your help, but it appears that kodi will receive a fix for this problem tomorrow on the nightly and unstable version, i was informed by an `Team-Kodi Member` on their forum (link [here](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=223200&pid=1973285#pid1973285)).

Answer (score 0):

The package & soname are different now, so it's `libgnutls-deb0-28`. Probably some apps will need to adjust their control files.

Comment: thanks, `libgnutls-deb0-28` is already installed, but at least now i know that i have to wait kodi be updated.